# Bad redirection after registration for free event

Tags: civievent, paypal, error-page, online-registration

I struggle a lot with this issue, and couldn't find anything to help me so I hope here could: 
I did set up an event, with different fees, and one of them is free. When people check not free, everything is going fine, but when they check free, they are not redirected correctly after "confirm your choice": the page is bugged and they do not receive any confirmation email. They are redirected on an error page (HTTP ERROR 500)
So, even though they are registered, they cannot see it and try again and again, registering each time. 
The payment method is Paypal. 
The CMS I am on is Joomla, and I use version 4.7.25 of CiviCRM.
This is a big problem and I don't see any way out, so thank you for your help.

Some screens :

[image: fees]

[image: confirm]

[image: error]

Comment: If Free - Then why to use Payment processor in the first place? - correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @INTA, welcome to CiviCRM SE! Can you please edit your question to include your version of CiviCRM and what CMS you are using. Thanks

Comment: Posting screenshot of error message and/or price fees will be very helpful to trace your problem.

Comment: @Ramesh actually there is different fees, and the other needs to be paid

Comment: @INTA - Please try to post some screen shot that should help

Comment: Sounds similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22049/fatal-error-using-paypal-in-version-4-7-29

Answer (score 1):

Its a known [bug](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-4449), and there is a patch to fix it. You can follow the following steps to fix it:

Open file: civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php 
Search for:

`$sub = empty( $params['is_recur'] ) ? 'xclick' : 'subscriptions';`

Replace with:

`$sub = empty( $params['is_recur'] ) ? 'cgi-bin/webscr' : 'subscriptions';`

It should be around line number 404

Hope it helps.