# Test payments not completing with Paypal website payments standard

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, ipn

I'm trying to troubleshoot some payment issues on a client site, and I'm noticing that although live payments are going through fine using Paypal website payments standard, test transactions are all being logged as 'Pending (incomplete transaction) despite the fact that the sandbox Paypal account is recording the transactions as successful and all the IPNs are getting a 200 response.

Any insights and/or troubleshooting tips most welcome.

Using Civi 4.7.29 and wordpress.

Comment: Did you find anything in CiviCRM logs? Can you also check if there is entry for payment processor callback in civicrm_system_log table for athe particular contribution.

Comment: Have you applied the patch?
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22049/fatal-error-using-paypal-in-version-4-7-29

Comment: I hadn't applied the patch as I wasn't aware of its existence. I'll check it out, thanks, but the report on the linked issue doesn't seem to match what I'm seeing.